# String that look the same but have different coding

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have two files: file1.csv and file2.csv, each one with the name "Aarão" written in the first and only line. file1.csv was generated from the "export as" of a Google spreadsheets; and the file2.csv was created manually by me, using nano. Both files are encoding in utf-8:

```
file -I file1.csv 
file1.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8

file -I file2.csv 
file2.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Both seem equal when I open them with nano but in fact are different:

```
>>> with io.open('file1.csv','r',encoding = 'utf8') as f1:
...     for line in f1:
...             word1 = line 
... 
>>> word1
u'Aara\u0303o\n'
>>> 
>>> with io.open('file2.csv','r',encoding = 'utf8') as f2:
...     for line in f2:
...             word2 = line
... 
>>> word2
u'Aar\xe3o\n'
```

So, how do I correct this problem, i.e., convert one into the other, so that I can check if they are the same word? (in python)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Comment: As a sid advice - since you are running single scripts, and moreonver, incvolving non-pure-ASCII text, you'd be much better of using Python3 than Python 2.7 there. Python 3 handling of text, with unicode by default, simplifies a lot of simple tasks.

(You'd still face the issue listed in the question, though - but you can open the file with normal the builtin `open`, and the CSV module works for it as well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As deceze, Serge, and Simon have mentioned, the `ã` glyph can be represented in either the composed form: a single codepoint (the codepoint for the `ã` character), or in the decomposed form: two codepoints (the codepoint for `a` followed by the codepoint for the combining tilde).

To convert between the composed & decomposed forms you can use the `normalize` function from the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) module. Here's a short Python 2 demo.

```
import unicodedata as ud

s = u"Aarão"
print repr(s)

decomp = ud.normalize('NFD', s)
print repr(decomp)

comp = ud.normalize('NFC', decomp)
print repr(comp), comp == s
```

**output**

```
u'Aar\xe3o'
u'Aara\u0303o'
u'Aar\xe3o' True
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the difference seems to be because of the two different strategies used to encode the ~a character.

```
'Aara\u0303o\n'
```

Contains the combining tilde character, while

```
'Aar\xe3o\n'
```

has ~a directly encoded.

Why this is  a problem, you do not say.

Comment: Ok, sorry. This is a problem because I have a list of thousand of names saved in the same conditions of file1.csv, and want to make them as stopwords when reading text from a file equivalent to file2. But since they are different encodings, I not able to correctly remove the names of file1 form the text of file2.

Answer (score 1):

The unicode character U+0303 is the combining tilde. It is a non spacing character, that means that it is added to the previous character.

You can control it in python (Python 2 syntax):

```
>>> print u'xa\u0303y'
xãy
```

That means that *visually* you cannot differentiate that from the a tilda character: U+e3:

```
>>> print u'x\xe3y'
xãy
```

but the are **different** (unicode) strings:

```
>>> u'xa\u0303y' == u'x\xe3y'
False
```

That just means that the Google spreadsheet contained the combining tilda while you manually entered the single latin1 character `ã`

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how do I convert one into the other? Because I want to check if they are the same word. In this case it is the same name, but just have different encodings.

Comment: @Miguel: No! It is not an encoding problem. It is visually the same glyph but with 2 distinct character representation. AFAIK, unicode has no provision to automatically convert one representation into the other

Comment: `unicodedata.normalize` can convert between the composed and decomposed forms.